# How to acess a object pk

Tags: django

I'm using the interactive shell console and am doing the following.

In `my_app.models`, I created this `Model`:

```
class Mercadoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

---

From the interactive shell:

```
from my_app.models import Mercadoria, Sell

mercadoria = Mercadoria.objects.all()

mercadoria

<QuerySet [<Mercadoria: Babydool>, <Mercadoria: Brinco>]>
```

How can I access a specific object taking as parameter my pk?

Comment: So you have a primary key, or you want the primary keys of the `Babydool` and `Brinco`?

Comment: i have the primary keys, and i want something like this


```
mercadoria.get(pk='babydool')

<Mercadoria: Babydool}>
```

Comment: well that will normally work, except that you fetch it with a lowercase `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of primary keys, you can obtain the `Mercadoria` objects with these keys with:

```
Mercadoria.objects.get(pk='Babydool')
```

where `'Babydool'` are here the primary keys for the object you want to retrieve.

If you want to perform a case insensitive matching, you can make use of the [**`__iexact`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact):

```
Mercadoria.objects.get(pk__iexact='babydool')
```

For example you can pass it to a template with:

```
def my_view(request):
    # …
    context = {
        'item': Mercadoria.objects.get(pk__iexact='babydool')
    }
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', context)
```

Then you can render this with:

```
{{ item }}: {{ item.price }}
```

Comment: ok, bot how i pass this Mercadoria,objects.get(pk='Babydool') to use on frontend.

Comment: @Bodok: you use this in the view, and pass it to the context of the template.

Comment: like im doing `mercadoria = Mercadoria.objects.all()` and `stuff_for_frontend = {"mercadoria": mercadoria}`........... but I'm not getting access

Comment: thx man, i already solve it, just a noob question